# I am trying to show a logo when the page scroll > 920

Tags: jquery, css

Hi I am trying to set a sidebar logo to only show when the page scroll reaches the next section without the logo space causing the page to jump

I am using the following code

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 920){
        $('#logo').show();
        $('#main-nav').css('top','0px');
    }
    else 
                $('#logo').hide();
                $('#main-nav').css('top','100px');
                endif
});
```

I thought I could use css to keep the space the same but it seems to add it to the space when the logo is visible?

any suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're code should work fine, I think you just have a few formatting / syntax errors.

See a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZjED3/

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 920) {
        $('#logo').show();
        $('#main-nav').css('top','0px');
    } else {
        $('#logo').hide();
        $('#main-nav').css('top','100px');
    }
});
```

With the above code, every time the page is scrolled it is manipulating the DOM. Adding Boolean variable to check whether it needs to be applied or not will stop the unnecessary calls, and will be more efficient.

See an updated working example here http://jsfiddle.net/zvg4m/1/

```
var pastWaypoint = false;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 920 && !pastWaypoint) {    
        $('#logo').show();
        $('#main-nav').css('top','0px');
        pastWaypoint = true;
    }
    else if ($(window).scrollTop() <= 920 && pastWaypoint)
    {
        $('#logo').hide();
        $('#main-nav').css('top','100px');
        pastWaypoint = false;
    }
});
```

With the above code the DOM manipulating calls will only be applied when the page is scrolled past 920 in either direction, rather than on every scroll event.

Answer (score 1):

Since jQuery Show() and Hide() work the same way as the css display property, you may want to try using visibility instead if you want the space for the logo to remain in the layout regardless of whether the logo is visible or not.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 920) {
        $('#logo').css('visibility','visible');
        $('#main-nav').css('top','0px');
    } else {
        $('#logo').css('visibility','hidden');
        $('#main-nav').css('top','100px');
    }
});
```

This may help with the page jumping issue.